# Trying to under a cachetest code in C

Tags: c, caching

I am trying to understand the following code and what it prints out exactly:

https://ideone.com/ddPVRe

```
           printf("Size (bytes):%9d, Stride (bytes):%4d, read+write:%6.2f ns\n",
           csize*sizeof(int), stride*sizeof(int),
           (double) sec*1e9/(steps*SAMPLE*stride*((limit-1)/stride+1)));
```

It stops at Size: 67108864 where R/W is 11.82 ns.

[image]

From what I can see it basically prints the time it takes to access the array x. Can someone please break it down for me?

Comment: The format string and the arguments doesn't match. The type of the result from `sizeof` is a `size_t`, which is an unsigned type of some implementation-specific width. You should be using e.g. `"%zu"` to print a `size_t` value. See [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for more details.

Comment: Break down what?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how would you optimize the code so the x array is accessed the same number of times as before
but in a way which reduce the average memory access time?

Answer (score 0):

Your code prints 3 values with some formatting features:

1. **Size (bytes):%9d**: this prints a %d value, which is a *decimal integer*. The 9 in between means that it prints at least 9 characters. If the number is represented by less than 9 numbers it fill with spaces. This value is taken from the second printf argument, csize*sizeof(int). As @Some programmer dude noticed, this operation returns a non signed number, so maybe you can change %d in %u
2. **Stride (bytes):%4d**: same as before, but only 4 characters as minimum lenght
3. **read+write:%6.2f ns**: prints a float value, minimum length is 6 character. The `.2` is the precision, the number of digits after the point.
4. **\n**: new line special character

Please refer to this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/
Ok, is cpp, but is more clear than the classic man page

Comment: This made it more clear. Thanks.I am trying to understand the two while loops. The first one basically accesses the cache and appends 1 to it however the second one confuses me

Comment: If this is all that is wondered about, then @unkowndude should probably get some beginners books to read. Even bad books would have explanations about `printf` and how it works, including the width and precision values.

Comment: @Some programmer dude Well, you are right, books contains all the informations, but for a beginner a couple of line like that may be confusing. Again I have always found difficulties in retrieving information about printf, I've never found a good source of help about stdio.h, and that's the reason I suggested to look in a c++ page.

Comment: Indeed, maybe the questions in the comments are not related to the main question, so please consider if you want to post new questions (and please follow guidelines in doing so)